# My email address is displaying an email which does not work. What do i do?

Tags: wp-admin

I bought my website domain a few days ago and i am having some trouble.

In the general section of my settings there is a field which asks from an Email address, in this section it says '(website name)@localhost.localdomain' this doesn't work and i am not sure what should be here or if this is supposed to be in this field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That's the e-mail address wp will be using to send you notifications, just switch to your e-mail address.

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate it. I though it was something like that but since i just bought the domain and this is the first time i have done something like this, i tend to overthink everything.